# Can not make an request for TokenCreateRQ 1.0.0

Tags: soap, sabre

I'm trying to make an request TokenCreateRQ on https://sws-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/ endpoint. Replaced required fields by my own credentials. Current credentials looks like next:

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <From>
                <PartyId>Agency</PartyId>
            </From>
            <To>
                <PartyId>Sabre_API</PartyId>
            </To>
            <ConversationId>2021.01.DevStudio</ConversationId>
            <Action>TokenCreateRQ</Action>
        </MessageHeader>
        <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <UsernameToken>
                <Username>my_username</Username>
                <Password>my_password</Password>
                <Organization>my_pcc</Organization>
                <Domain>DEFAULT</Domain>
            </UsernameToken>
        </Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <TokenCreateRQ Version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com"/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and response comes following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">Sabre_API</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">Agency</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:ConversationId>2021.01.DevStudio</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Action>ErrorRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>2746048641716630381</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2021-09-14T17:49:31</eb:Timestamp>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"/>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <soap-env:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap-env:Client.AuthenticationFailed</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Authentication failed</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <StackTrace>com.sabre.universalservices.base.security.AuthenticationException: errors.authentication.USG_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED</StackTrace>
            </detail>
        </soap-env:Fault>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Credentials are correct. Does anybody knows what may cause an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Probable cause, your credentials are not activated to consume Sabre webservices or you might have to reset your password.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).